# How to store YugabyteDB snapshots in S3 compatible object storage

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Looking at the docs and I’ve successfully taken a snapshot of my cluster.
Are there instructions on how to store YugabyteDB backup on s3 compatible object storage?

Answer (score 0):

Check out at the end of the page https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/manage/backup-restore/snapshot-ysql/, there's a script that can help you.

The [yb_backup.py](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/blob/master/managed/devops/bin/yb_backup.py) script automates all the steps needed to take a snapshot and move the files into NFS,AWS S3,Azure Blob and Google Cloud Storage.